# Serverless command "offline" not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverless, serverless-offline

I am running my nodejs code and also installed serverless(**npm i -g serverless**) but while running it with the command `sls offline start --CacheInvalidations` I am getting error as:-

**Serverless Error ---------------------------------------**

Serverless command "offline" not found. Did you mean "config"? Run "serverless help" for a list of all available commands.

Get Support --------------------------------------------

```
 Docs:          docs.serverless.com
 Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
 Issues:        forum.serverless.com
```

Your Environment Information ---------------------------

```
 Operating System:          linux
 Node Version:              12.18.2
 Framework Version:         1.79.0
 Plugin Version:            3.7.1
 SDK Version:               2.3.1
 Components Version:        2.34.6
```

Comment: In my case, I had the module correctly under node_modules and still it was not working. I found the issue that I was executing the command >sls offline start from the base application folder, but you have to execute the command from the SERVICE_FOLDER. Hope this might help somebody....

Comment: in my case i had to run `sudo npm install serverless -g` and worked like a charm

Answer (score 19):

You need to install the `serverless-offline` plugin using npm in order to use `sls offline` command.

Just simply run:

```
npm i -g serverless-offline
```

to install globally on your device
or

```
npm i serverless-offline --save-dev
```

to install it as a development dependency in the active project.
and then add this configuration to your serverless template:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

For more information on `serverless-offline` plugin take a look at serverless official documents:

[Serverless Offline | Emulate AWS λ and API Gateway locally when developing your Serverless project](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline#installation)

[Serverless Offline NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline)

Comment: make sure you hit save on your serverless template, I'm used to work with auto saving IDE, so when I switched to something else I forgot to save after adding the plugin

Comment: ok, one more important thing is that `serverless.yaml` has to be in the same folder where the `node_modules` folder is

Comment: @Madeo but serverless generally while creating a project it's going to create folder right, can we point out the plugin to refer one folder up is that possible ?

Comment: I had the same problem, the serverless.yml was in `src` instead in the root project. 30 minutes lost forever

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue while setting up serverless.yml with nodejs and running it on local. Two steps resolved the problem.

1. Install serverless-offline package globally.

`npm i -g serverless-offline`

2. Add the same package under the plugin key of your serverless.yml file.

`plugins:` 
 `- serverless-offline`

Answer (score 2):

Installing the dependency with [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) you can run the command typing the following:

Install:

```
yarn add serverless-offline -D
```

Run:

```
yarn serverless offline start
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to try with

```
 npx serverless plugin install --name serverless-offline
```

this is for install serverless-offline plugin.
you also can view available plugin names bu

```
npx sls plugin list
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the package (or locally in your project or globally). I do recommend install globally.

```
npm i -g serverless-offline
```

or

```
yarn global add serverless-offline
```

Inside your serverless.yml file, add in the plugins session the following code:

plugins:

- serverless-offline

It will sove your problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved this issue but I was having the same problem, for me it was a silly error, the indentation of the YML file was wrong, after fixing the indentation it started to work just fine

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to install serverless offline globally.

```
npm i -g serverless-offline
```

Next, you should check a serverless.yml file. Otherwise, you must create a serverless.yml file.

```
service: your-service-name
app: app-name
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  timeout: 60
  memorySize: 128
  deploymentBucket: bucket-name
# you can overwrite defaults here
  stage: prod
  region: your-aws-region
functions:
  your-function-name:
    handler: handler.dispatch
    memorySize: 128
    timeout: 60
    events:
      #- http: POST /hello
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-aws-alias
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure serverless-offline is installed (globaly or at the project)
2. Add these lines to serverless.yml

```js
plugins:
  # Needed to run & debug locally
  - serverless-offline
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in your project with the `npx` prefix. So `npx sls offline` or `npx serverless offline`. It worked for me.