# Serverless command "offline" not found Node 14.X

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, nestjs, serverless, aws-serverless

### Description problem

I have a problem with serverless-offline because I try to install this local and global, and it doesn't work.

[serverless-offline image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etz97.png)

###### When executing the command I get this information

```hs
sls offline
```

> Serverless command "offline" not found. Run "serverless help" for a list of all available commands.

###### This is my configuration in the serverless file.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${env:NODE_ENV}

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-offline
```

###### This commands I used to install

In the machine environment

> npm i -g serverless-offline

In the file project:

> yarn add serverless-offline -D

[Issue in git](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/1292)

[Serverles environment configurated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOCye.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try in your project with the `npx` prefix. So `npx sls offline` or `npx serverless offline`.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but it has not worked. :+1:

Comment: Make sure serverless-offline is installed in your project as well via `npm i serverless-offline` or `npm i -g serverless-offline`. That counts for all plugins. More similar issues at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507149/serverless-command-offline-not-found

Comment: I already fixed it; I have nvm on my computer, so I installed serverless on the latest version of the node, and I also had the need to install ```serverless-plugin-optimize``` because then this error jumped:
```Serverless: To ensure safe major version updates, make sure to set "framework version" in the service settings (recommended setting: "framework version: ^ 2.66.1").```

I don't know why but I execute:
```serverless offline``` and worked.
I think there is not a good solution, but it's working.

Comment: I tried many solutions but this did work for me. Thank you